# Proper way to include files

Tags: python

I am trying to keep a somewhat organized directory structure as I plan to add more and more scripts. So lets say I have a structure like this:

```
/src/main.py
/src/db/<all my DB conn & table manipulation scripts>
/src/api/<all my scripts that call different APIs>
```

My main.py script will include certain classes from db & api folders as needed. I have the blank _____init_____.py files in each folder so they are included fine. But say I want to include a class from the db folder in a script in the api folder? Like I would need to back up one dir somehow? The api scripts fail when I have a line like this in them:

```
from db.Conn import QADB
```

I am on v2.6.

Update: I have tried a relative import, but get this?

```
from ..db.Conn import QADB 
     ^ SyntaxError: 
invalid syntax
```

Comment: do you have a /src/__init__.py file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you have it setup is creating three different modules - this may or may not be what you want to do. If you want a common module which can manage different tasks you could arrange it as follows:

```
mymodule
 |- __init__.py
 |--database
 |   |- __init__.py
 |   |- dbclasses.py
 | 
 |--api
 |   |- __init__.py
 |   |- apiclasses.py
 |
 |--other

[etc]
```

If you have it like this and want to use the API and database functionalities, you can start by saying:

```
from mymodule.database.dbclasses import MyDBClass
from mymodule.api.apiclasses import MyAPIClass
```

Notice the way you had it: the name of your top "module" was `src` (it was not a module because it did not have an `__init__.py` file).

If you use many common functionalities in the top module (from either submodule) you can include them in the top `__init__.py` and simply call `from mymodule import MyDBClass, MyAPIClass`.

Contents of top `__init__.py`:

```
from mymodule.database.dbclasses import MyDBClass
from mymodule.api.apiclasses import MyAPIClass
__all__ = ['MyDBClass', 'MyAPIClass']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use relative imports:

```
from ..db.Conn import QADB
```

Comment: Hah. I didn't even bother to try that. Thought it would completely fail. That's what I get I suppose. But I get this error:


    from ..db.Conn import QADB
         ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: After meddling with them several times, relative imports are still a mystery to me.

Comment: If the src folder is a package, then you could import from there as well: from src.db import QADB

Comment: @ Hallik: as Gabi mentioned in the question comments, you must be missing the `__init__.py` file in the top-level `src` directory.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I don't like that structure. Base your structure on what scripts do. What if you want to write a script that calls an external database API. Does that go in the API directory or the db directory?

And yeah, use relative inputs as awesomo suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Move everything under a common package:

```
mypkg/main.py
mypkg/db/...
mypkg/api/..
```

then use the absolute import

```
from mypkg.db.stuff import somestuff
```

This way you can also distribute mypkg as an egg.